# Offline Programming Education for Kids

Tags: linux, software-development, offline, educational

I am building out a Raspbian install for an eight year old to learn programming concepts, and I am looking for software recommendations.  My question is similar to [Programming environment to teach kids about the concepts of programming](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/programming-environment-to-teach-kids-about-the-concepts-of-programming), except that my target student will have no way to access the internet, or to reach out to me for help (they reside in a 3rd world country with electricity, but no connectivity).

I have seen several compelling online resources like codeacademy, and even some installable options like python turtle and scratch, but I'd like advice on how to make these applications usable with no internet.  For instance, is there a simple way for me to download python turtle documentation and make it available locally for my student?

Comment: Your question seems to have a few questions within it, some of which do not belong on this site. For instance, could you explain what specifically you're looking for be it software to download and store locally documentation or a software environment that can be used offline for a Rasbian?

Comment: Either of those options would suffice.  My end goal is a self-contained, offline education course for an eight year old to learn programming concepts.  There are tons of online games and tools like lightbot, and several installable options which require you to access online documentation.  I am looking for any software recommendation that would replicate this experience offline.